# Casio CT-X8000IN not working blank blue screen

Tags: piano

I have a Casio CT-X8000IN which I bought from India. It was working good for 6-7 months, but then I realized it has a lot of dust in it. I opened it and found out there was a lot of a dust, I cleared it out with a painting brush, and then I put back the piano body and fixed all the screws properly. I am not a tech guy and don't know about Motherboards, CPU etc. So when I started the Piano , there was a blank blue screen and then.... nothing. I waited for it but it was stuck on blue screen. Nothing was working, even the buttons and keys weren't working. My guess is that it is a motherboard failure. Am I right or wrong? What could be the real reason? Should I take it to the service center?

Comment: It's *possible* that you disconnected the display by mistake, open it again and check near the display if it has a connector plate and verify it's properly inserted in its slot. Be very careful, as they are very delicate.

Comment: @musicamante But apparently nothing is working, it might be worse than that but obviously impossible to see remotely. Maybe you should ask an electronic repair shop to have a look?

Comment: Yeah I am thinking @Tom. I was just asking if you have any ideas what is wrong.

Comment: @musicamante I didn't do nothing. I just cleaned it. And there Is a blue screen and it's stuck on it and nothing is responding. Some problem with software?

Comment: In some situations, even disconnecting a display could result in total failure, it completely depends on how the hardware is connected and how the "software" handles missing "responses" from certain components. Maybe you didn't disconnect the display, but something else. And I don't mean that you did it on purpose, it could be some cable or connector that was just stuck somewhere, and when you opened it (or closed it) it got disconnected. Try to open it one more time and see if there's any cable or connector around, otherwise find an electronic repair shop.

Comment: any chance you touched any of the circuits? I'm not an expert but I wonder if static electricity could have corrupted an EEPROM or something

Comment: Yes @topoReinstateMonica I am thinking i might have. all the above comments are right

Comment: For next time, look into *anti static wrist straps*. Of course this may not be the problem, it's just a thought. I hope your keyboard can be repaired!